# handling hibernate UnsupportedOperationException: Can't write to a readonly object

Tags: java, hibernate

What configuration parameters or session preferences do I need to set to fix this? Can't write to a readonly object? Here is the stacktrace for more information:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't write to a readonly object
        at org.hibernate.cache.ReadOnlyCache.lock(ReadOnlyCache.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:85)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:248)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:232)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:140)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
        at com.mycompany.arch.submission.registry.bean.RegSubmissionSpringService.perform_flush(RegSubmissionSpringService.java:1108)
        at com.mycompany.arch.submission.registry.bean.RegSubmissionSpringService.saveRegistryData(RegSubmissionSpringService.java:1062)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy145.saveRegistryData(Unknown Source)
        at com.mycompany.arch.submission.registry.bean.RegDataAccessManager.persistRegistry(RegDataAccessManager.java:54)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See if this [blog page](https://kyrylkov.com/2005/12/04/cant-write-to-a-readonly-object-with-hibernate-read-only-second-level-cache/) is useful:

> Check that your Hibernate class
>   mapping has mutable="false", which
>   prevents Hibernate from issuing
>   updates for already existing
>   instances. Here is a link to my
>   Hibernate Forums thread about this
>   problem.

Comment: that link seems broken I think it should point to: - http://sergiy.kyrylkov.name/2005/12/04/cant-write-to-a-readonly-object-with-hibernate-read-only-second-level-cache/

Answer (score 9):

For the lazy/stupid people amongst us (like me ;))

changing

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
```

into

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
```

(for example)

(in the database type pojo)

might help too :)

S.

Comment: Correct, the value of that enumeration is self explanatory. I did the same thing and it worked for me.